# Android 2.1 Emulator Without Internet Connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, dns, internet-connection

I have no Internet access in my Android Emulator.

The app I am developing needs Internet connection, but the Android Emulator have no internet connection. I also tried to use the native browser of the emulator, but it also does not work.
When I export my app to a real android, it works just fine.

I already tried to press F8 to turn on and off the "3G connection" in the emulator.

I already turned off the Windows Firewall, but it didn't work.

Data:
Windows 7 x64
Eclipse Plugin for Android
Android version 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set manually the DNS Server of my emulator.

To do that:

Within Eclipse I went to Run Configurations -> Target and added "-dns-server X.X.X.X" and everything worked fine afterwards. (obviously X.X.X.X was the IP address for my DNS server).

so i put this line: -debug-slirp -dns-server 192.168.178.1

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the emulator instance. Sometimes the instances get corrupted and you get weird behavior like the one described by you above. The internet connection should work without any interaction in a fresh emulator instance.

If you are behind a firewall or you are using a proxy then things can get a bit more complicated but there are workarounds for those situations also.

Comment: I already tried to create the emulator instance hundreds of times.
And I am not under a specific firewall, just the regular windows 7's firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep re-creating new instances of the same emulator.  I had this problem before and created a brand new emulator (same settings as the other one), and it worked fine for some reason.