# Android v2.1 emulator is not able to connect the internet

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, emulation, android-internet

I already checked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4376553/1481665) & [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2039964/1481665) links but I think my problem is different as follows:

My **Android 2.1 emulator is not able to connect the internet** via my app/emulator default browser yet I am **able to connect the internet from my other Android version emulator(s)**.

My computer is directly connected through internet, I checked my firewall settings & its probably ok. Several times re-started & created new 2.1 emulator, but not able to connect it.

***>>*** How is this possible from the same mechine and with the same configuration; other android powered emulators working fine, but android 2.1 emulator have problem ?

**Snapshot of Android 2.1 emulator with its default browser:**

[image: Android 2.1 emulator snapshot of its default browser.]

Comment: I had this very same problem when working at university project, but I don't remember if the problem was the university proxy or the fact that I was under a WPA Wi-Fi network. Are any of there your scenarios?

Comment: Yes, many peoples faced the proxy problem..but here I don't have any proxy. My laptop is directly connected with internet. And more than that other emulators working fine, but 2.1 is not :(

Comment: Restart your emulator and than try again.it happens several times.

Comment: I already done the following things: restarted, created a new, checked & compared the emulator settings with other version emulators. but problem not solved. :(

Comment: Try to start the emulator with the "Wipe User Data" checkbox as selected. See if that solves the problem, assuming that you have tried all recommendations put in the above comments.

Comment: where is the "Wipe User Data" checkbox ?

Answer (score 1):

Some useful link that I hope can help you:

[No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

[Android Emulator - No internet connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899967/android-emulator-no-internet-connectivity)

[Android 2.1 Emulator Without Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309741/android-2-1-emulator-without-internet-connection)

[No internet connection on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620548/no-internet-connection-on-android-emulator)

[Android emulator no internet connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801204/android-emulator-no-internet-connectivity)

[How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Comment: I checked all the links, 1st, 3rd & last one  is may be useful for others but not worked for me. I take the steps described as accepted answer as per link 3, but it not works(and the comment on that ans also shows that the ans not works).